# IONIC debug error - AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, compiler-errors, android-manifest, cordova-plugins

I have been trying to install the 'cordova-plugin-local-notification' plugin for a few days and it keeps giving me problems, I have had to reinstall several plugins such as 'cordova-plugin-device', 'cordova-plugin-ble-central' and ' cordova-plugin-badge'.

Since then, it keeps throwing the error:

```
AAPT: error: unexpected element \<queries\> found in \<manifest\>
```

**VERSIONS**

```
> Ionic:
>
> Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.10
> @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
>
> Cordova:
>
> Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
> Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
> Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 27 other plugins)
>
> Utility:
>
> cordova-res : 0.15.4
> native-run  : not installed
>
> System:
>
> Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\\Users\\desarrolloapp\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk)
> NodeJS            : v14.18.0 (C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe)
> npm               : 2.15.12
> OS                : Windows 10
```

**ERROR**

```
 C:\_programacion\\cordova\\demo\>ionic cordova build android --prod

 ionic-app-scripts.cmd build --prod --target cordova --platform android

 > \[08:44:55\]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.4
 > \[08:44:55\]  build prod started ...
 > \[08:44:55\]  clean started ...
 > \[08:44:55\]  clean finished in 33 ms
 > \[08:44:55\]  copy started ...
 > \[08:44:55\]  deeplinks started ...
 > \[08:44:56\]  deeplinks finished in 929 ms
 > \[08:44:56\]  ngc started ...
 > \[08:45:23\]  ngc finished in 26.45 s
 > \[08:45:23\]  preprocess started ...  
 > \[08:45:23\]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
 > \[08:45:23\]  webpack started ...  
 > \[08:45:23\]  copy finished in 27.95 s
 > \[08:46:12\]  webpack finished in 49.03 s
 > \[08:46:12\]  uglify started ...
 > \[08:46:12\]  sass started ...
 > \[08:46:16\]  sass finished in 4.27 s
 > \[08:46:16\]  cleancss started ...
 > \[08:46:19\]  cleancss finished in 3.09 s
 > \[08:47:03\]  uglify finished in 50.92 s
 > \[08:47:03\]  postprocess started ...
 > \[08:47:03\]  postprocess finished in 82 ms
 > \[08:47:03\]  lint started ...
 > \[08:47:03\]  build prod finished in 127.69 s
 > \[08:47:11\]  lint finished in 8.14 s
 > cordova.cmd build android
 > Discovered saved plugin "mx.ferreyra.callnumber". Adding it to the project
 > Plugin "call-number" already installed on android.
 > Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
 > ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\\Users\\desarrolloapp\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk (recommended setting)
 > ANDROID_HOME=C:\\Users\\desarrolloapp\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
 > Subproject Path: CordovaLib
 > Subproject Path: app

 Configure project :app
 WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
 It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

 Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
 Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
 Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
 Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
 Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
 Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
 Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
 Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
 Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
 Task :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
 Task :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
 Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
 Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
 Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
 Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
 Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
 Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
 Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
 Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

 Android resource linking failed
 C:\_programacion\\cordova\\demo\\platforms\\android\\app\\build\\intermediates\\merged_manifests\\debug\\AndroidManifest.xml:46: AAPT: error: unexpected element \<queries\> found in \<manifest\>.

 Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 Get more help at 23 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 22 up-to-date
 https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 7s
 C:\_programacion\\cordova\\demo\\platforms\\android\\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

 Android resource linking failed
 C:\_programacion\\cordova\\demo\\platforms\\android\\app\\build\\intermediates\\merged_manifests\\debug\\AndroidManifest.xml:46: AAPT: error: unexpected element \<queries\> found in \<manifest\>.

 Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 7s
 \[ERROR\] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

 cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

 Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="demo"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:versionCode="959"
    android:versionName="0.0.959" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="23"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data android:scheme="geo" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- for android -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/> -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/> -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" /> -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" /> -->
    <!-- for Samsung -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" /> <!-- for htc -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT" /> <!-- for sony -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE" /> <!-- for apex -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT" /> <!-- for solid -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE" /> <!-- for huawei -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" /> <!-- for ZUK -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE" /> <!-- for OPPO -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" /> <!-- for EvMe -->
    <uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ" />
    <uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE" />

    <application
        android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:supportsRtl="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="demo.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:label="@string/activity_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity"
            android:label="Share" />

        <provider
            android:name="de.appplant.cordova.emailcomposer.Provider"
            android:authorities="demo.emailcomposer.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/emailcomposer_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <provider
            android:name="io.github.pwlin.cordova.plugins.fileopener2.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="demo.opener.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/opener_paths" />
        </provider>
        <provider
            android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="demo.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="launchnavigator.GOOGLE_API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

        <provider
            android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.util.AssetProvider"
            android:authorities="demo.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/localnotification_provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <receiver
            android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.TriggerReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />
        <receiver
            android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClearReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClickReceiver"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've tried installing several versions of gradle.
v4.10.3, v5.6.2, v6.8.3, v7.3.3, v7.4, v8.3

Also delete plugins, node-modules, platform and compile directories to recreate the project.

Add 'xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" to the root widget tag of config.xml'  to the root widget tag of config.xml

Thanks

Comment: Use Capacitor version.

Comment: Thank you, but to do this I would have to transfer the entire project to the latest ionic 7, I think it would take a long time and it is not easy.